# Liferay web service

Tags: web-services, soap, liferay

I use Liferay 6.1.1-ce-ga2 bundled with Tomcat server and Oracle 10g database.
My goal is to insert some content, as Journal Article, and display them in an Asset Publisher (with a structure and template, already working).

I used `JournalArticleServiceSoap.addArticle(...)` with the right fields `(groupid, structureid, templateid, ...)`. The contents are "correctly" inserted in the database and I can see them inside web contents from administrator content panel. The contents have also `"Approved"` as status. This is done by setting:

```
serviceContext.setWorkflowAction(WorkflowConstants.ACTION_PUBLISH)
```

However, I can't see the inserted contents displayed with the other contents in the Asset Publisher, until I open it again for edition and click on publish button (even without changing nothing). Then the content is published as expected. The problem is the number of contents. It is about 600 so I can't to this action for each one.

I do not understand what is the matter and how to figure it out? In other words, what do I have to do to make the web-content inserted by web service display automatically in Asset Publisher?

Or, what does the `"Publish"` do exactly so I can try to reproduce programmatically with SOAP service (or SQL after insertion)?

Thank you in advance for your help.

<sub>I've also posted the same question in Liferay' forum: [Problem to display JournalArticle inserted by SOAP web service](http://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/view_message/23098918)</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try to log the database accessing from Liferay and see what will be changed after you save article manualy. Herefor set the logging level of hibernate to info or debug.

Comment: Where can I log the database accessing from Liferay using hibernate level? Thx

Comment: Alright, I find the way log the database by adding the following in portal-ext.properties `hibernate.show_sql=true
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=info`. The addArticle(...) method and the Publish action seem to use the same SQL actions (insert and update). I am trying to understand the hundred of line code and I will share if I find the solution.

Answer (score 0):

are you setting serviceContext like this?

```
ServiceContext serviceContext = new ServiceContext();
serviceContext.setAddGuestPermissions(true);
serviceContext.setAddGroupPermissions(true);
serviceContext.setScopeGroupId(groupId);
serviceContext.setWorkflowAction(WorkflowConstants.ACTION_PUBLISH);
```

Comment: Yes Mariol, my setting is like that but it still doesn't working. For information, in the `journalArticleServiceSoap.addArticle` method I've replaced the structureId by null because, it seems in the 6.1.1 version of liferay, setting this value causes a java.rmi.RemoteException.

Comment: Of course in the database I replace the structureId by the right value. Also when I compare (in DB) the inserted row and another one, I can't see any difference.

Comment: I was looking to some code I wrote and founded that I used WorkflowConstants.STATUS_APPROVED instead of WorkflowConstants.ACTION_PUBLISH

Comment: Now the content is inserted with "Approved" status. But it still not displayed directly and I have to publish it again via LR "Publish" button.

Answer (score 0):

You must setting serviceContext Like This:

```
   ServiceContext serviceContext = new ServiceContext();
    //serviceContext.setAddGuestPermissions(true);
    //serviceContext.setAddGroupPermissions(true);
    serviceContext.setScopeGroupId(groupId);
    serviceContext.setWorkflowAction(1);
    serviceContext.setIndexingEnabled(true);
```

serviceContext.setIndexingEnabled(true); is Very Important.

The following code is not  must requeired.

```
serviceContext.setAddGuestPermissions(true);

serviceContext.setAddGroupPermissions(true);
```